# How to make sure 2 async functions are executed before when connection state becomes done?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, flutter

I am using `FutureBuilder` like this -

`FutureBuilder(
        future: _future,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          return snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done
              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : Text('Done');
        },
      ),`

In `initState`, I am calling `_future = getData();`

`getData` calls two async functions which are getting called only after the connection state is becoming done. What check should I put to make sure that progress indicator is shown until both the functions are executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well assuming that the execution order of your async functions aren't important you  can do something like:

```
initState(){
    _future = Future.wait( [yourAsyncFunc1(), yourAsyncFunc2()] );
 }
```

In this case `yourAsyncFunc1()` and `yourAsyncFunc2()` are the `async` functions that you call inside your `getData` function. `Future.wait(..., ...)` call returns immediately a future object but this future only completes after `yourAsyncFunc1` and `yourAsyncFunc2` execution are done. So you can use FutureBuilder widget with `_future` in `future` property and see the results.

Answer (score -1):

Use async function with awaits.

Something like

```
Future<void> getData() async {
  await future1Function();
  await future2Function();
}
```

Comment: Yes I did that. Connection state becomes done before these functions are completed. These functions are interacting with the server and fetching some information.

Comment: Use `snapshot.hasData` instead.

Comment: My functions aren't returning any values.

Comment: In that case FutureBuilder is not that ideal solution for you. 

Instead of FutureBuilder just have `bool isDone = false` on your widget state class. 

In your getData() function do your requests, and after do `setState({isDone = true})`,

In your build() function do return `isDone ? Text('Done') : CircularProgressIndicator()`.

Comment: I don't want to `setState` and build my widget tree again. I am sure there is must way to do it using `FutureBuilder`.